# Как сделать цикл и прервать его с помощью нажатия клавиши?

Tags: python, клавиатура, bind

У меня есть определенный цикл биндов, то есть для каждого бинда какое либо действие. Как мне сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку <kbd>Enter</kbd> все бинды отключились и программа начала выполнять нужные мне действия?

Comment: Зачем плодить огромную кучу дубликатов?

Comment: @Глеб, ну такая задача у меня

Comment: Ну просто минусов наловите и все.

Comment: @Глеб, можно поподробнее? Мне нужна реализация данного задания.

Comment: Пока что в любом случае вопрос не совсем понятен, даже если не считать, что это дубликат и обсуждать надо в основном вопросе. Нет кода, примеров, объяснения недостаточно.

Comment: break в помощь .

Answer (score 0):

функция перестанет выполняться после нажатия на `enter`

```
import keyboard

def my_loop():
    while True:
        # Тело цикла
        print("Цикл выполняется...")
        # Другие операции внутри цикла
        
        # Проверка нажатия клавиши
        if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
            print("Цикл прерван по нажатию клавиши 'enter'")
            break

my_loop()
```

Comment: мне нужно использовать root.bind